# What is the difference between session resumption in TLS v1.1vs TLS v1.2?

Tags: azure, session, tls1.2, tls1.1

**Scenario**: We are planning to implement Session resumption to reduce data usage to handle multiple reconnect issue.

Our Azure system is using tls v1.1 , I just checked *Session resumption* is available in **tls v1.1**. All these days I was in an assumption it is only available in **tls v1.2**.

**Question**:
Can someone tell me should I really want to upgrade towards **tls v1.2** or I can stay with **tls v1.1** itself to achieve the same ?

**Reference:** https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4346#appendix-F.1.4

Any suggestion guys ?

Comment: What service is that? Your own custom TLS listener in a VM? I'm asking because no platform service in Azure (PaaS) is capped at TLS 1.1, they all support TLS 1.2.

Comment: Yes , we have custom Listener. I want to know whats the difference. Should I really need to go with TLS 1.2

Comment: I don't know of any common modern TLS stack that can do 1.1 and can't do TLS 1.2. I would definitely support resumption in 1.2. Think 3-5 years in the future, you're gonna see TLS 1.2 as the minimum standard and TLS 1.3 as the recommendation (well, one can hope).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no easy answer to this. There are several factors that have to be taken into account:

- Do all of your client stacks support **TLS 1.2**?
- Is the application functionality tested with **TLS 1.2**?

If answer to the above is yes, then you could enforce TLS 1.2. However, there might be other scenarios, that I might have taken into account. So you will have to do a run through of the scenarios that can possible exist.